# Calculate expected value of $H_t=exp(W_t/(1+t))$

Tags: exponential-function, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, expected-value

If $W_t$ is a Wiener Process/Brownian motion standard, what is the expectation of:

$H_t=exp(W_t/(1+t))$

I know the answer is:

$E(H_t)=exp(t/(2(1+t)^2))$

But the solution I find is $1/2*exp(t/(2(1+t)^2))*erf((t(x-1)+x)/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(t)*(t+1))$

How can I do this? I can't do the passages!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your working/understanding of the problem to receive a good response from MSE community.

Comment: I can't do the passages

Answer (score 1):

For $t\geq 0$, we have :
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[H_t] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{W_t}{1+t}\right)\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t}}_\alpha X\right)\right] \quad X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\alpha x -\frac12x^2\right)dx \\
&=\underbrace{\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12(x-\alpha)^2\right)dx}_A\exp(\frac12\alpha^2) \\
&= \exp\left(\frac12\alpha^2\right)
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the fact that the quantity $A$ is the p.d.f of gaussian variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I love you, this was exactly what I was wandering.